# Mortgage question: Which banking terms mean "lends smaller amounts" or "offers small mortgage loans"?

Tags: mortgage, lending

Despite many phone calls I haven't been able to find a lender who offers home loans under 100k USD. Which banking terms are used to specify lenders who do "small" mortgage loans? I'm going with an FHA loan but that probably wouldn't change the terminology used for such lenders.

Comment: Try contacting a mortgage broker rather than a lender.  They should be able to identify those lenders which can meet your borrowing requirements.

Comment: You may have already seen this, but this article highlights some of the problems you will face : https://www.mortgageloan.com/challenge-getting-small-mortgage-9886

Comment: Thanks. Also, a mortgage broker was my choice from the beginning for the "shop around" benefit, but after hard pulling my credit the multiple brokers I'd applied with said they didn't do loans under 100k. Ouch!

Comment: Get a loan that lets you make additional payments against principal, borrow $100k, pay back the excess immediately after closing?

Comment: @keshlam that may bring the LTV to above the maximum allowed at closing, depending on the property value.

Comment: Where in the US are you? The mortgage company I used when we bought our house would do "small" mortgages. So does PNC, and both of  my credit unions.

Comment: I have had several HELOC (home equity line of credit) loans for less than 100K

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking for either a credit union or a small-town bank if you're looking for a "small" (sub-$100k) mortgage.  Larger banks and lenders don't like such loans because there's not enough margin for them in reselling the loan to a servicer.  Credit unions and small-town banks tend to hold on to the loans they originate, so they're more likely to be willing to originate a mortgage for you.

I hope this helps.

Good luck!